# What is the Quadratic trigonometric Nu Spline basis functions?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, computational-mathematics, spline

can someone help me identify what is exactly the **quadratic trigonometric Nu spline basis function** based on an article *"A Quadratic Trigonometric Nu Spline with Shape Control"*

here is the doi link address for the article : https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219467817500152